# Run Rails app as non-root user, but ask for root password to access files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, permissions, user-permissions, systemmanagement

I have been given the task to make the source files of a Rails application non-readable without providing a password (root user's password), so the client won't be able to peek inside the application (which will run on a machine which will be kept in a server-room at the client's).

I tried changing the ownership of all the application folder (and files, and subfolders etc.) to root, and set permissions to execute-only for "other" users... But to no avail: I achieved the non-readability of the files for the non-root user, but it was also impossible to run the app.

Running `sudo rails ...` didn't work either with these permissions.

The machine is running Ubuntu 14.04. The app is based on Rails 4.2 and Ruby v2.2.1p85, and actually runs behind nginx and is using unicorn (+ thin as integrated web server)... If that ever makes a difference. The machine is set to start and automatically login the only non-root user (say `company`) without asking for a password, and to immediately launch unicorn.

One thing I still haven't tried, because I think it might be too invasive of an operation, is creating a new user account, say `client`, and have the machine autologin this new account. While leaving `company` as the owner of the app files and folders, I would set Ubuntu to run unicorn as a different user from the logged in one (i.e. `company` vs. `client`) and it would be impossible to open the file in a reader.

How can I achieve my goal, if it is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Following your first approach by changing permissions of all files, why don't you try to set `the set-user-ID-on-execution bit`:

```
chmod -R 4701 <app_dir>
```

This will prevent "other" users from reading and will allow them to execute, but while executing they will gain the privileges of the owner (which is the interest of `set-user-ID`).

P.S. I don't know if this would work for you but it worths trying.

Comment: Could be an acceptable idea, but I cannot even start the application when i `unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.conf.rb`.  Any way to set the application folder owner to a different user (`www-data`, `rails`, whatever works...) and then launch the application as that user, while still logging in `company` at boot?